# When preventing Enter key to submit AJAX form focus on next input isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

A small problem which I can't find a solution for (maybe I googled with wrong keywords):

**The situation:**

I prevent a form being submitted by hitting the Enter Key (13). 
To be noted that the form will be submitted by AJAX, **therefore there will be no page reload.**

Preventing the Enter Key is a simple task and it works:

```
$(document).on('keypress', 'input', function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

**The problem:**

The focus on the next input is not working **because of the `return false`**.

If I omit the `return false` part, naturally the form is submitted by AJAX  **and the `focus()` is working.**

```
$(document).on('keypress', 'input', function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        // Simplifying the selector of the next input
        // because this isn't the problem
        $(this).next().focus();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Any ideas on how to solve that?

Comment: please provide some html..

Comment: It has nothing to do with HTML, The form is correct.

Comment: try this .. `$(this).next('input').focus()`;

Comment: Please read carefully: *If I omit the `return false` part, naturally the form is submitted by AJAX  **and the `focus()` is working.***

Comment: try this `$(this).nextAll('input').first().focus();`

Comment: @PsycoKillers Please read the question...

Comment: Yes I have read it. Try using the codes I am providing.

Comment: And as a matter of fact you do not have provided complete information. And FYI you just have provided js. How can we know where is location of input you want to be focused ...

Comment: If I tell you that the focus is working when omiting the return false! why downvote if you don't get the problem?

Comment: Can you try by calling a function in your if condition and having $(this).next().focus(); in that function. In the callback function you can return false to prevent form submit. Not sure if this would work or not but worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by calling a function in your `if` condition and having `$(this).next().focus();` in that function. In the `callback` function you can `return false` to prevent form submit.